# CFNetwork internal error when load multiple images from local JSON file into tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, uiimageview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"ChatCell";
    ChatCell *cell = \[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"\];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        \[tableView registerNib:\[UINib nibWithNibName:cellIdentifier bundle:nil\] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"myCell"\];

        cell = \[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"\];
    }

    ChatData *chatData = \[self.loadedChatData objectAtIndex:\[indexPath row\]\];

    \[cell.images sd_setImageWithURL:\[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dev.apppartner.com/AppPartnerProgrammerTest/images/justin_avatar.png,http://dev.apppartner.com/AppPartnerProgrammerTest/images/drew_avatar.png"\]placeholderImage:\[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"\]\];
    \[cell loadWithData:chatData\];

    return cell;
}
```

[image: code]

Why am I getting a CFNetwork internal error when I try to load multiple images from a local json file into my tableview?

Comment: Where do you load from a local file? What is the actual error? Which line of code?

Comment: Yes I am loading my images froma a local file @rmaddy

Comment: I am not sure if that is the cause of the error. However, if it is what should I do @SausageMachine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because that your `url` is not found on server, I mean your url (`http://dev.apppartner.com/AppPartnerProgrammerTest/images/justin_avatar.png,http://dev.apppartner.com/AppPartnerProgrammerTest/images/drew_avatar.png`) is wrong. If I open this url in browser then it throws `error 404` like `The requested URL /AppPartnerProgrammerTest/images/justin_avatar.png,http://dev.apppartner.com/AppPartnerProgrammerTest/images/drew_avatar.png was not found on this server.` You can try to open this url in browser. Otherwise your code seems to be alright. there is no problem with code i think!!!

Comment: I get the same error however, I am loading all my images from a local json

Comment: you're right! My url is not a server. I think that was the issue!